# How do I change these mappings to have a nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following mapping, but I'm not sure how to change it so that ESK knows that individual-package-categories is a nested field.

```
PUT /durationsmapping/_mapping
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "individual-package-categories" : { 
          "properties" : {
            "activity" : {
              "type": "nested" 
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "duration" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "time-set" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Elastic >= 7.x
PUT /durationsmapping
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "individual-package-categories" : { 
          "type": "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "activity" : { 
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "duration" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "time-set" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }

For Elastic < 7.x
PUT /durationsmapping
{
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc": {
        "properties" : {
          "individual-package-categories" : { 
            "type": "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "activity" : { 
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "duration" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "time-set" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it gave me the following error:

Comment: "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={individual-package-categories={type=nested, properties={duration={type=long}, activity={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, time-set={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}}}]"

Comment: That's correct, I updated my answer. Please note, that if you are using the _mappings endpoint, you do not need to specify "mappings" in the document body.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: When I try to access the nested data, I can see it in the discover tab, but I can't access it in visualization.